# Restart Mac OS X ungracefully using a C++ call?

Tags: c++, macos, restart, reboot

How do I restart Mac OS X using **C++** (*not Objetive-C*) without invoking any child processes? Don't care if it's *ungraceful*.

```
system("reboot"); //Is not acceptable as it relies on invoking a process
```

Comment: What's wrong with invoking a process?

Comment: Now why would you want to do such thing?

Comment: You don't need to write C++ code to do that. Just flip the power switch.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to ask how to launch a child process with the same privs as your process?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't think why you wouldn't want to create a new process, but if you really don't want to, then `execve("reboot",0,0)` will run `reboot`, replacing the current process. You'll need to include `<unistd.h>`.

I'm assuming this is available on Mac OS; it should be on all POSIX platforms.

**UPDATE**

It appears that Mac OS has a [`reboot`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/reboot.2.html) system call. `reboot(RB_AUTOBOOT);` might do what you want. Or it might trash your hard drive. Be very careful when trying to work against the operating system like this.

Comment: I can't invoke a process. That still does it. If I invoke a process it runs as an unprivileged used because my application is run with a suid bit.

Answer (score 0):

JMP 0xFFFF0

:-)