# How to reboot Mac OS from C++

Tags: c++, macos, operating-system, reboot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Restart Mac OS X ungracefully using a C++ call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3386983/restart-mac-os-x-ungracefully-using-a-c-call)

All,

I am trying to reboot a Mac from my code. I find no such thing on the web. 
Has anyone done that?

Comment: Technically this is not allowed at the application level. You must ask the OS to do it for you. The OS will probably ask the user before actually doing the shutdown(). As it is part of the OS it is technically not part of C++.

Comment: how do I ask the OS to do it including asking the user...

Answer (score 2):

On UNIX-like systems this should work:

```
system("shutdown -r now");
```

Comment: Unless you are root this is going to result in a denied.